# Get author's first name

Tags: author

I am probably being a little dumb here, but can anyone point me in the right direction.

I am trying simply display the authors first name as a link in my loop.

But the doesnt seem to be any options with the `get_author` tag.

This is what I got so far.

```
Posted by <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" rel="author"><?php printf( __( '%s' ), get_the_author() ); ?></a>
```

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `get_the_author_meta( 'first_name' );` (see [Codex for `get_the_author_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta))

Comment: I could not find that page for some reason. Thanks.